# Lost my Seed Words for MetaMask

Tags: metamask, keystore

I am very shocked. After a crash on my computer, I lost my Seed Words file to access my MetaMask account. However, I found a Keystore file (UTC or json file), but when I import it into MetaMask I can not find my Ethereum. I'll get another ETH adress and there is no ETH in my wallet.. How is this possible? And how do I get back into my old account without Seed Words, but with UTC keystore file? If this succeeds, it will make me very happy!

Kind regards,

Koen

Comment: When you have restored MetaMask from seed phrase You can restore, But without seed you can not recover. https://metamask.helpscoutdocs.com/article/58-metamask-basics

Comment: You may find https://metasafe.org useful

Answer (score 2):

> There is unfortunately nothing you can do to recover your wallet at
>   this point, 
>  The seed phrase is the only way to restore your
>   account.

https://metamask.helpscoutdocs.com/article/58-metamask-basics

> The Seed Words for accounts is the primary way to back up multiple
>   accounts, Keystores are for individual accounts.

https://kb.myetherwallet.com/private-keys-passwords/difference-beween-private-key-and-keystore-file.html

Comment: The Seed Words for accounts is the primary way to back up multiple accounts, keystores are for individual accounts,  https://kb.myetherwallet.com/private-keys-passwords/difference-beween-private-key-and-keystore-file.html

Comment: Aaaai.. That sucks. And MetaMask can't do anything? So the ETH is gone?

Comment: If you had your seed words stored in a text file on your hard disk (which is generally a bad idea, but it sounds like you might have), then it's conceivable that you could use specialist recovery tools to find it. Otherwise, your seed is your account.

Comment: If you have seed words you can restore multiple accounts and with the keystore or privatekey you can restore individual account, If anything happens to your data (MetaMask installation, hard-disk, whole machine), then your account cannot be restored without a backup of the Seed Phrase.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to retrieve your accounts without mnemonic/seed words. Your account is all lost. Now you will have to create a fresh MetaMask account. Mnemonic words are used to retrieve your account, public key, and private key. This is a unidirectional process. You can't do the vice-versa.

Comment: This is not completely true: depending upon if you can recover the wallet "vault" file directly. If you remember the wallet lock password, you can [recover it](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018766351-How-to-use-the-Vault-Decryptor-with-the-MetaMask-Vault-Data) with the [raw vault data](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015289852-How-to-Copy-Your-Vault-Data).